# Function com retorno usando 'case when'

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho uma function que me retorna o status de um pedido (no banco está como int) que só tem dois possíveis valores, 0 (inativo), 1 (ativo). Eu estava tentando incrementá-la com 'case when' para caso o resultado seja 0 ela me retorne 'Pedido Inativo' ou se o resultado for 1 ela me retorne 'Pedido Ativo'. Abaixo a minha function:

```
create function NumPedidoStatus(@cod int)
returns int
as 
begin
    declare @Retorno int
    set @Retorno=(select status from pedido where idPedido = @cod) 
    return @Retorno
end
```

O que eu tentei fazer foi pegar o valor do retorno e usá-lo no 'case when', só que constantemente encontrei vários erros e não consegui fazer do jeito que descrevi acima.

Terminou que não consegui fazer e gostaria que alguém pudesse me ajudar o que devo modificar nessa function para que ela opere do modo que desejo.

OBS.: Estou usando o SQL SERVER

Comment: qual o erro que tu esta tendo?

Comment: Eu tive vários erros e não anotei quase nada, mas teve um que lembro que ocorreu mais de uma vez. Foi esse: "create function must be the only statement in the batch". Mas acredito que eu não estava conseguindo inserir o case when corretamente, esse acho que era o grande problema.

Comment: A relação na sua tabela  **pedido**  retorna _um para um_ no `where idPedido = @cod`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

certo para usar o case when seria da seguinte forma.

```
select case when status = 0 then 'Pedido Ativo' else 'Pedido Inativo' end as Status from pedido where idPedido = @cod)
```

mas nesse seu caso tem duas opções de uso
Continuando com seu comando:

```
 create function NumPedidoStatus(@cod int)
 returns varchar(25)
 as 
 begin
    declare @Retorno int
    set @Retorno=(select status from pedido where idPedido = @cod) 
    if @Retorno = 0
       begin
         return 'Pedido Inativo'
       end
    else 
       begin 
          return 'Pedido Ativo'
       end;
 end
```

ou senao utilizando o case when:

```
 create function NumPedidoStatus(@cod int)
 returns varchar(25)
 as 
 begin
    declare @Retorno varchar(25)
    set @Retorno=(select case when status = 0 then 'Pedido Ativo' 
                         else 'Pedido Inativo' end as Status from pedido 
                   where idPedido = @cod)) 
    return @Retorno
 end
```

Comment: A segunda opção ajudou, mas tem um parêntesis a mais depois do @cod que deve ser retirado

Answer (score 1):

Rodando em SQLServer o `case` é assim:

```
SELECT  
   CASE 
      WHEN [colunainteira] = 1 THEN 'um' 
      WHEN [colunainteira] = 0 THEN 'zero'
   END 
  FROM ...
```